# The service "…" has a dependency on a non-existent service "property_accessor" when upgrading to Symfony 5.3

Tags: symfony, symfony5, nelmio-alice, liiptestfixturesbundle

We have an issue with the bundle https://github.com/liip/LiipTestFixturesBundle/tree/2.x (please note that I'm one of the maintainers of this bundle, the issue is not about using that bundle in a project)

[Tests were broken](https://github.com/liip/LiipTestFixturesBundle/runs/2748014748?check_suite_focus=true) on the main `2.x` branch with the following error:

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: The service "nelmio_alice.property_accessor.std" has a dependency on a non-existent service "property_accessor". Did you mean this: "nelmio_alice.property_accessor.std"?

Here is how that service is declared in `vendor/nelmio/alice/src/Bridge/Symfony/Resources/config/property_access.xml`:

```xml
        <service id="nelmio_alice.property_accessor.std"
                 class="Nelmio\Alice\PropertyAccess\StdPropertyAccessor">
           <argument type="service" id="property_accessor" />
        </service>
```

This code should be called because `NelmioAliceBundle` is loaded in `AppKernel`.

So we [added](https://github.com/liip/LiipTestFixturesBundle/pull/126/commits/bda3f033897c53216e0f6962dbf4d7b093a84e37) this to `composer.json` to forbid `symfony/property-access 5.3` and it fixed the error:

```json
"symfony/property-access": "^4.4 || ^5.0 , <5.3",
```

But if we remove that workaround, it breaks again. And I don't understand what is causing this issue.

Forbidding `symfony/framework-bundle` 5.3 also fixes the issue: https://github.com/liip/LiipTestFixturesBundle/pull/127/commits/a534419e61ef90ca2685d697b89b2ce225712cdc

---

What is causing the absence of `property_accessor` when we use `symfony/framework-bundle` 5.3 or `symfony/property-access` 5.3?

---

### How to replicate the error

```
git clone git@github.com:liip/LiipTestFixturesBundle.git
cd LiipTestFixturesBundle
git checkout remove-required-symfony/property-access
composer install
vendor/bin/phpunit --testdox tests/Test/ConfigEventsTest.php
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I can depend on `PropertyAccessorInterface` fine on Sf 5.3.

Comment: Additionally, following the steps in the question, tests pass alright. https://cln.sh/J7kQJ6

Comment: @yivi I updated the question, thanks. I opened a PR from that branch, tests are broken: https://github.com/liip/LiipTestFixturesBundle/pull/130

Comment: Again, I followed the instructions to the letter, I do not get any error.

Comment: You have an issue somewhere in how you updated to 5.3.  With a fresh 5.3 (no additional bundles) the property_accessor service is right there ready to be used.

Comment: @Cerad we didn't do anything special to update to 5.3. It was released, GitHub Actions used it, and it broke. It [this change](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.4/UPGRADE-5.3.md#propertyaccess) relate to that issue?

Comment: Does not seem likely but maybe.  The fact that you have an AppKernel indicates a legacy app which can always be a bit tricky to update.  I know you filed a PR but I think you might want to open an issue as well.  There was already one on 5.3 issues but it seems to be resolved.  Be sure to include php version.  Good luck.

Comment: @Cerad thanks for the idea, I [upgraded the Kernel](https://github.com/liip/LiipTestFixturesBundle/pull/127/commits/bb113709b8c156d60015babd5f763e5e7d5ccbb9) but it broke some other things and the service is still missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `property_access: ~` to the `framework` configuration fixed the issue ([commit](https://github.com/liip/LiipTestFixturesBundle/pull/130/commits/7f793d8d2ba36f784344e0c23091173c67067324)).

It looks like the service was missing when it wasn't configured.

---

The issue is reproducible on a fresh Symfony install:

```
$ bin/console debug:container property_accessor
[critical] Error thrown while running command "debug:container property_accessor". Message: "No services found that match "property_accessor"."

                                                     
  No services found that match "property_accessor".
```

If you have that issue too, run `composer require symfony/property-access`.